# create an array or list with different element sizes python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to create an array or list with different element size however, I got the output not as expected with a word array written in the middle of the array as in the following:

```
import numpy as np
lst_2=np.array([1,2,np.repeat(3,3),2],dtype="object")
print(lst_2) 
#Output is=[ 1 2 array([3,3,3]) 2]
#lst_2 should be = [1,2,3,3,3,2]......
```

please any help or suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing lists and numpy arrays. I presume what you want to achieve is a numpy array that looks as follows:

```
import numpy as np
lst_2=np.concatenate([np.array([1,2]), np.repeat(3,3),[2]])
print(lst_2)
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3 3 3 2]
```

Alternatively you can also use the following if you want a list:

```
lst_2 = [1,2] + list(np.repeat(3,3)) + [2]
```

The plus operator here stands for concatenation of two lists. Whereas the plus operator stands for elementwise addition in case of numpy arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, it works perfectly 
However, lst_2 will be from an input so I would like to avoid adding np.array, inside each element, 
Do you have any suggestion or advice, or how could I have an array or list then add [] for each number later ??

Thank you,

Comment: keep in mind that `+` for lists is join, but addition for arrays.